# Linux kernel has better response time under stress

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, latency

I have a stange behavior that I fail to understand:
For performance measurement purpose, I'm using the 'old' parrallel port interface to generate IRQs on a debian kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64 (I am using an externel signal generator connected to tha ACK pin).

I wrote my own kernel module (top half only) to handle the interrupt and send an external signal back to the parrallel port and display both signals on a oscilloscope so I can measure the kernel response time.
Everything works as expected and I can see an average 70 µs of time response with some 'burst' of 20µs . I'm running on a "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz".

Now, the "unexplained" part.
If I load the CPU, memory and I/O using the "stress" program, I expected the average time to be worst , but the opposit happens: my average response time drops to 20µs.
I tried on 3 differents kernel:
vanilla, PREEMT-RT anf vanilla with NO_HZ option set to false.
Can someone explain the magic of this ?

I change the 'governor' configuration to 'performance' but doesn't change anything.

Comment: See [apm_32.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/kernel/apm_32.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12#n908).  You can try to boot with *cpuidle.off=1 idle=poll  apm=off*, etc.  There are all sorts of factors, like cache, SDRAM auto-power down, etc.  As opposed to a *scope*, you should use some kernel profiling tools which can give a better answer.  They will zero in on where extra time is spent.

Answer (score 6):

Your interrupt handler has a higher priority than the stress program.
So the only influence the stress program has is to prevent the CPU from sleeping, which avoids the delay needed by the CPU to wake up from the sleeping state when an interrupt arrives.